# Read Double integers from file Swift

Tags: ios, swift

I have this piece of code, which reads integers from a file and puts it into an array:

```
 array = data.characters.split(){$0 == ","}.flatMap{
(Int(String.init($0).stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet(NSCharacterSet.whitespaceCharacterSet())))}
```

So for example if I have a line of numbers separated by a comma like so : `1,2,3,4` my array will be `[1,2,3,4]`. 
My question is, how do I change this code so that `Double` are also read from this file? E.g `1.2,3.4,5.6` will be `[1.2,3.4,5.6]`. At the moment my code ignores these digits altogether. Thank you.

Comment: `1.2` is *not* an integer ..,

Comment: @MartinR Apologies, typo, edited the question.

Comment: @user3395936 you just need to change from Int(..) to Double(...)

Comment: @LeoDabus I have tried that before, and also received the same suggestion from users in the comments section but I get an error. See below for reference.

Comment: @user3395936 you should edit your question/post and add the actual code or at least a verifiable example

Comment: `let str = "1.2, 3.4, 5.6";
let arr = str.componentsSeparatedByString(",").flatMap{ Double($0.stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet(.whitespaceCharacterSet())) }`

Comment: @LeoDabus your suggestion brings this error : ` Cannot convert value of type '(_) -> Double?' to expected argument type '(String) -> _'`

Comment: @LeoDabus also my other code is not doing anything that relates to my question otherwise I would have included it.

Comment: My suggestion works as it is. After the changes you have made it gives that message

Comment: @LeoDabus Actually, you are totally correct. This works with the code you have provided, and I just tweaked my code a little and it worked too. Thank you very much :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/109374/discussion-between-leo-dabus-and-user3395936).

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want Doubles (not Double Integers, whatever that is) since your values have a decimal portion, you should be able to just make your code cast the value to Doubles instead of Ints:

```
array = data.characters.split(){$0 == ","}.flatMap
{
  (Double(String.init($0)
    .stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet(NSCharacterSet.whitespaceCharacterSet())))
}
```

Comment: Brings me this error : `Cannot convert value of type '(_) -> Double?' to expected argument type '(SubSequence) -> _'` And yes you are right, it was my typo, edited my question.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
array = data.characters.split(){$0 == ","}.flatMap{ (String.init(Double($0)).stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet(NSCharacterSet.whitespaceCharacterSet()))}
```

Comment: Brings me this error : `Cannot convert value of type '(_) -> Double?' to expected argument type '(SubSequence) -> _'`

Comment: Please try the above change as Double($0) rather than ($0)

Comment: Unfortunately still the same error : `Cannot invoke initializer for type 'Double' with an argument list of type '((SubSequence))'`